# How to schedule learning rate decay based on metrics for stable baselines 3?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I want to write a learning rate schedule based on logged metrics. The API's doc provides example for linear decaying (https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/examples.html#learning-rate-schedule) and examples can be found for exponential decaying. Is it a way to perform parametric decaying (loss based) ? Is it relevant with adam optimizer (which is already adaptive) ?